# How can I configure Google Chrome to never open a type of links with some associated app?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, links

How can I configure Google Chrome to never open a type of links with some associated app?

For example, I don't want to see the following notification and instead never use the associated program for `URL:slack`

[image]